# Функция error_log почему выдает свой ответ сервера

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, юзаю функцию error_log(), сервер отдает сообщение:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://адрес_сайта/?">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

ни где в описании не находил подобного. Мне надо чтобы сохранился лог в системном журнале, к которому имеется доступ через cpanel, а ответы сервера сам уже формирую. Но в том логе он ничего не сохраняет и выводить свой ответ клиенту. В чем проблема как убрать вывод этого хтмла или какое имеется решение?

хостинг виртуальный, доступа к настройкам не имею

P.S.: `<?php error_log(date('Y-d-m H:i:s').' sid='.$_POST['sid'].'; os='.$_POST['os'].';ver='.$_POST['v'], 0);exit; ?>`

Comment: php код в студию

Comment: <?php error_log(date('Y-d-m H:i:s').' sid='.$_POST['sid'].'; os='.$_POST['os'].';ver='.$_POST['v'], 0);exit; ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php)

Вам следует либо настроить [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log), либо изменить 2-ой и 3-ий параметры на свои:

```
error_log($log, 3, '/home/site/error_log/Site_User_errors.log');
```

т.е. путь указать лога, который кушается от cpanel

еще есть подозрение, что до error_log не доходит, и выдает ошибку до нее.

Comment: да, действительно не доходило до нужно страницы